# Java - Next function

Tags: java

everyone. I'm new to java and I have a quick question regarding the next function in the linked list. Here is my code:

//Wrong Method

```
    public class Class {
    public static void main(String [] args) { 
    Node a = new Node ("A"); 
    Node b = new Node ("B"); 
    Node c = new Node ("C"); 
    Node d = new Node ("D");
    a.next = b; b.next = c; c.next = d;
    System.out.print(a);
}
}

class Node {
String value;
Node next;

public Node (String value) {this.value = value;}
public String toString() {System.out.print(value + "," + next); return "";}
}
```

//Output is: D,nullC,B,A,

I have try the following methods and the output is same (A,B,C,D,null) which is correct:

//Method 1

```
 public class Class {
    public static void main(String [] args) { 
    Node a = new Node ("A"); 
    Node b = new Node ("B"); 
    Node c = new Node ("C"); 
    Node d = new Node ("D");
    a.next = b; b.next = c; c.next = d;
    System.out.print(a);
}
}

class Node {
String value;
Node next;

public Node (String value) {this.value = value; System.out.print(value + ",");}
public String toString() {return next + "";}
}
```

//Method 2:

```
public class Class {
    public static void main(String [] args) { 
    Node a = new Node ("A"); 
    Node b = new Node ("B"); 
    Node c = new Node ("C"); 
    Node d = new Node ("D");
    a.next = b; b.next = c; c.next = d;
    System.out.print(a);
}
}

class Node {
String value;
Node next;

public Node (String value) {this.value = value;}
public String toString() {System.out.print(value + ","); return next + "";}
}

public String toString() {return value + "," + next + "";}
```

So I'm confused why the very first method is wrong? System.out.print(value + ",") works fine with (return next + "";) in Method 1 & 2. So I'm thinking System.out.print() has no conflict with return. Yet System.out.print(value + "," + next) is wrong. Thanks a lot for answering my question. Have a wonderful week!

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking here.

Comment: Note that there is no "next" _function_ in your code, only a "next" reference/variable.

Comment: Why don't you just do: `public String toString() {return value + "," + next;}`?

Answer (score 0):

Why does "wrong method" produce `D,null,C,B,A`? That's because  `value + "," + next` will cause `toString()` to be called on `next` if it isn't null. So `toString()`will be recursively called before printing.

What happens is basically this (indentation indicates call hierarchy/call stack):

- `System.out.print(a);` calls `a.toString()`

  - `a.toString()` tries to produce the string `value + "," + next` which calls `b.toString()` (since `a.next == b`)

    - `b.toString()` tries to produce the string `value + "," + next` which calls `c.toString()` (since `b.next == c`)

      - `c.toString()` tries to produce the string `value + "," + next` which calls `d.toString()` (since `c.next == d`)

        - `d.toString()` tries to produce the string `value + "," + next`. Since `d.next` is `null` this produces and prints `"D,null"`.
      - the call to `d.toString()` returns `""` so now `c.toString()` produces and prints `"C,"`
    - the call to `c.toString()` returns `""` so now `b.toString()` produces and prints `"B,"`
  - the call to `b.toString()` returns `""` so now `a.toString()` produces and prints `"A,"`

As you can see, `"D,null"`, `"C,"`, `"B,"` and `"A,"` are printed in that order and without any newline characters so the output will be `"D,nullC,B,A"`

If you want to produce `"A,B,C,D,null"` you need to use the following:

```
public String toString() { return value + "," + next; }
```

Using the same call hierarchy as above here's what will happen:

- Recursive calls down to `d.toString()` which returns `"D,null"`.
- `c.toString()` now uses that return value for "next", so `value + "," + next` now results in `"C" + "," + "D,null"` = `"C,D,null"`.

  - the same happens for `a.toString()` and `b.toString()` to the end result will be `"A" + "," + ("B" + "," + ("C" + "," + ("D" + "," + null)))` = `"A,B,C,D,null"` (each parenthesis represents a nested call to `toString()`).

Answer (score 0):

In the first method, the line

```
System.out.print(value + "," + next);
```

effectively translates to

```
System.out.print(value + "," + next.toString());
```

Hence, `next.toString()` is called first to determine what should be passed to `System.out.print()`. Hence, the call order is actually as follows:

```
System.out.print(d.value + "," + null);
System.out.print(c.value + "," + d.toString());
System.out.print(b.value + "," + c.toString());
System.out.print(a.value + "," + b.toString());
```

Furthermore, given that you always `return ""`, `next.toString()` always evaluates to an empty string:

```
System.out.print(d.value + "," + null);
System.out.print(c.value + ",");
System.out.print(b.value + ",");
System.out.print(a.value + ",");
```

Some general best practices that I would recommend you to follow:

1. `toString()` should do one thing and one thing only: Create a string representation of the object and `return` that. If anyone calls your `toString()` that's what they expect. Anything else is unexpected and may catch a caller of your class by surprise.
2. Use a debugger (by placing a so-called breakpoint in your code). The debugger allows you to inspect the current state of all variables and it allows you to step through your code one instruction at a time. This allows you to understand what your program is actually doing.